# How to output a line in the command prompt

Tags: cmd

I've seen people using a file that makes the command prompt output data to the console. Basically how can I make the command prompt output a line of code of my choosing like in Python's print() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `echo thing` if you want to echo thing

Be sure to add `@echo off` to the top of your .bat file